# Way to Add Values into a N-Dimensional Dictionary without nested if-else in Swift?

Tags: swift

For example, I have 2D dictionary that tells the sums of numbers. `sums[2][2] == 4` because 2 + 2 = 4. I have initialized the dictionary with some values:

```
var sums = [1: [1: 2, 2: 3], 2: [1: 3, 2: 4]]
```

Now I want to insert `sums[3][4] == 7` to my 2D dictionary. I tried different ways to insert it and I get some problems:

```
sums[3]?[4] = 7     // Does not work because the key 3 is not in dictionary.
sums[3] = [4: 7]    // Does not work because if 3 exists, it would overwrite.
```

Yes, I can write an if-else statement but the number of if-else statements would grow relative to the dictionary dimension. Is there a swifty way to deal with this?

```
// This works but does not scale
if var innerDict = sums[3] {
    innerDict[4] = 7
} else {
    sums[3] = [4: 7]
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Now I want to insert sums[3][4] == 7 to my 2D dictionary"?

Comment: “not really elegant” That’s a matter of opinion. Even Superman has to put on his tights one leg at a time.

Comment: Sorry, not a boolean value, but make the dictionary contain the key: 3 which leads into another dictionary where I want a key/value pair of 4: 7.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the subscript with a `default:` parameter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2894528-subscript):

```
sums[3, default: [:]][4] = 7
```

You can make this into an extension if you use nested dictionaries a lot:

```
protocol DictionarySubscriptable {
    associatedtype Key
    associatedtype Value
    subscript(key: Key) -> Value? { get set }
    init()
}

extension Dictionary : DictionarySubscriptable {}

extension Dictionary where Value : DictionarySubscriptable {
    subscript(_ key1: Key, key2: Value.Key) -> Value.Value? {
        get {
            self[key1]?[key2]
        }
        set {
            self[key1, default: .init()][key2] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can do:

```
sums[3, 4] = 7
```

Comment: Thank you! This is kind of what I was looking for but, when I scale the dictionary to have 3 keys instead of 2, I do not want to recreate this function again and again (same for 4, 5, 6 or more keys). Is there anyway to generalize the solution?

Comment: @Kousei Gosh, why are you using such deeply nested dictionaries? IMO 2 levels is still acceptable in some situations, but any more than that, you should question your design... Maybe use a your own struct (that has multiple properties) as the key instead? You can also consider writing your own tree structure, if that's what you need. And no you can't generalise the solution, at least not in a type safe way.